# Magento 2 - where to find \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory

Tags: magento2, catalog, magento2.3.4

In **vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php** you can find this parameter in the constructor:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory $productImageFactory
```

but where is the class located? I searched in **vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\** but there is no such file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factories are service classes that instantiate non-injectable classes, You do not need to explicitly define them because they are an automatically generated class type. When you reference a factory in a class constructor, Magento’s object manager generates the factory class if it does not exist

You will find the `Image.php` file at:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
```

Factory class generated by Magento and stored in `generated` directory. You will find the factory class at:

```
generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/ImageFactory.php
```

For more information about Factories check the link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/factories.html

Hope this helps!